# How to reference the Application object from another project in the same solution?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I have a solution containing two projects: a windows phone project and an authentication library.

In the authentication library I want to reference the phone project's App.xaml.cs in code.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

The right thing to do is to move the code that you want to use in both libraries to a separate assembly and reference this assembly from both of your projects.